# add additional static value while writing to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to add city='Delhi' and age=25 along with person name list and write it to csv.

```
import csv
p1 = ['Peter', 'Sam', 'Mike']
city = ['Delhi']
Age = ['25']
def write_to_csv(name):
    with open('person.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\n')
        writer.writerow(name)
write_to_csv(p1)
```

Current O/P

Peter

Sam

Mike

**Required output**

Peter,Delhi,25

Sam,Delhi,25

Mike,Delhi,25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding \n line terminator o/p looks good.Thanks

```
import csv
p1 = ['Peter', 'Sam', 'Mike']
city ='Delhi'
Age = '25'
def write_to_csv(name):
    with open('person.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        for i in range(len(name)):
            writer.writerow([name[i], city, Age])

write_to_csv(p1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through each element

```
  def write_to_csv(name):
       with open('person.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for i in range(len(name)):
                writer.writerow([name[i],city[0],Age[0]])
```

Comment: missing `)` after `range(len(name)`

Comment: also, when I run your code the output is not as requested